# characters missing when printing

Tags: pdf, printing

We have a WPF application which can perform either a report preview or a report print.
Both requests use the same code.

- Call the report service which gets the report from Microsoft Report Services.
- Convert the report into the desired format (in this case PDF).
- Then return the report as a byte array.

The result is then written to a temporary file as a binary stream, and either popped into a window to preview or start a Process to print.

In both cases the temporary file is passed.

Print Preview works flawlessly!  But Print Report will print with all occurances of 'ti' disappearing.  I see there is a printer escape sequence of ESC t NUL/SOH and I assume that if, for some reason, an escape character gets into that stream that ti will result in an ignored print sequence.  Thus the missing characters.

My first question is if anyone has ever experienced this with generated PDF reports?

My second question (obviously) is if anyone knows of a utility I can use to view the binary data in the file being printed, to see what is in the file just before every 'ti' sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a great deal of searching I came across a post on the Adobe forum that states that version 8 had a bug where it was not printing character combinations.  Once I dug deeper it seems that it has returned and the suggested workaround fixed our issue.

Workaround: Do a print as image.

Adobe seems to be unable to do the most basic of what their software must do, print the exact content!

Answer (score 2):

Answer for your *second* question:

- First, do one of the following two things:

  1. Set the Windows print spooler properties to not delete printed jobs.
  2. Pause the target print queue.
- Then, grab the spool file from the Windows printspool directory (which location that is you can find out by looking at the (right-click) *'Properties...'* dialog of the 'Printers and Faxes' folder).

Comment: One thing I found was a file hex viewer at http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/ which is letting me look at the files.

Comment: @SASS_Shooter: so did my answer help you to lasso the files or not?

Comment: @SASS_Shooter: *Of course* my answer would have helped you to lasso the files had you even tried it! Your one question was: *"...anyone knows of a utility I can use to view the binary data in the file being printed..."*. But I understand that this wouldn't necessarily have helped you to solve the problem.

Comment: Actually I did use both the viewing of the file and the lasso of the print spool file.  It helped me to view it but not solve the problem.

Comment: y@SASS_Shooter: our question was about viewing the file (implying that you could solve the problem once you could only view the binary)!

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post but I wanted to add some updated info from the above comment stating that it's a problem with Acrobat 8.  We are using Acrobat 10.1.6 and still have the same problem.  From what I've read, it's a problem with the adobe product itself.  The only real fix I've seen (actually work around) is to print as an image.  LAME

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly this bug is still there in 2021. Adobe cannot be relied upon printing documents properly. This takes away all the allure of features it had if it cannot do the most basic stuff it is required for.

Printing as image reduces the quality and blur the document.

Simply open the document with Safari or Chrome and print from there. E

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem while printing directly from the firefox (acrobat reader within). I downloaded the file and then printed. The problem was solved.